# corps (singular and plural)

Tags: word-usage

> corps

It's known that this word, corps has the same form for singular and plural forms but the pronunciation is different: singular /kɔː(r)/ and plural /kɔːrz/

Is there any particular, distinct type of usage for this word as singular and plural?

Edit: the pronunciation is really different when it's singular or plural?

Comment: Have you done any research? I got [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/corps-plural-singular) (detailed explanation of ‘corps’ at M-W) from a cursory Google search.

Comment: corps is corps. The Army Corps of Engineers. It is invariable.

Comment: What if everything is in a dictioary or on the internet and people only refer to them?

Comment: If it is in the dictionary and people refer to them, that would be great.  Please do that!

Comment: It's a French loanword. "Corps" in French means "body," so in English, "corps" (pronounced just like "core") is singular and refers to a plurality formed into a singular "body" (e.g., the Marine Corps). When we pluralize it in speech, we pluralize it according to English's rules for pluralization, so we add a soft S and pronounce it like we do "cores" (e.g., Two corps of scientists worked the problem, one sent by the government and the other sent by the local university.), but it's still written "corps" since the the standard English alternatives "corpss" and "corpses" are problematic.

Comment: By the way, it's not unusual for a spelling to have two different pronunciations in English for different intended meanings, like "wind" is pronounced with a long i when it refers to what one does to a watch but is pronounced with a short i when it refers to air that blows.